# how to highlight image latest image in winjs listview...?

Tags: microsoft-metro, winjs

### how to highlight image latest image in winjs listview

I am working on a winJS application.I need to highlight latest image in winJS list view.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a `CSS3` selector:

```
.win-listview img:last-child {
    /* highlight style */
}
```

To select and modify in JS:

```
var listview = document.querySelector('.win-listview');
var firstChild = listview.firstChild();
// Perform any needed action to firstChild
```

Comment: how to change the height of the first child in winJS ListView..?

Comment: @user2194939 Same selector but with :first-child

Comment: how to change the height of the first child in winJS ListView..?And i need to add custom data to that cell.